# Wanting to write a gay kiss... for young audiences

Tags: young-adult, middle-grade, young-author

I wanted to write a gay kiss at the close end of my third book. I already started their chemistry with each other on the first and more in the second now it's leading up to the kiss. I have a ton of readers and some already ship my characters together. Now if I write it I might be afraid people won't approve it. I'm scared, I planned this pairing from the start and if I can't show them who they are maybe I can't show myself...

Help!

Comment: Thank you for putting gay characters into your book - especially one targeted at a young audience! Representation is important, not for the political points you'll score, but because you will allow LGBTQ kids to understand themselves better. (I certainly wish I had read stories with gay relationships when I was younger, I might have figured myself out a lot sooner.)

Answer (score 10):

I feel like advice that was given to me about writing characters of the opposite gender also applies here. **Just write it as if it were a regular kiss with individuals of separate genders.** Of course you may need to make exceptions for anatomy, but I think what would be more important in this is the build up to the scene, rather than the scene itself. Regardless of character genders in any book, if it doesn't seem like the natural progression of the story, then it may just come across more jarring and you would loose suspension of disbelief for the reader to go, "what?".

If the readers are already turned off by the existing chemistry, likelihood is they aren't going to reach the end of the book anyway. With that in mind, I personally feel like YA novels that drop big relationship surprises at the end really turned me off from a series. If there was a buildup that I wanted something to happen and it finally happens in the last few pages, it feels satisfying. However, whenever I have read a series that tried to drop it as some sort of twist hook for the next book when it made little sense for the story, I usually just dropped the series all together. *I'm talking to you James Patterson.*

Answer (score 4):

A kiss is just a kiss.

It's not a gay kiss as far as writing is concerned.

Lips are lips. Maybe they both have beards or something but...the same feelings and actions you would have in a hetero kiss, you would have in what you are calling a gay kiss.

The real issue is this:

> Now if I write it I might be afraid people won't approve it.

Thing is, there will be people who don't approve of your writing, gay or not. Some will disapprove because of the gay. If that's your fear, I am not here to tell you that will not happen. I am just here to say that you should accept it, not fear it.